# Set optimistic locking as global option in node , sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to set up sequelize in my node project and for now I have

```
//sequelize init
const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: database,
  username: user,
  host: server, 
  password: password,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      useUTC: true,
      dateFirst: 1,
    }
  },
  define:{
      timestamps:false,
      paranoid:false,
      freezeTableName: true
  }
});

//and my Model 
  const User= sequelize.define('User', {
    // attributes
    id: {
      field:'Id',
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    } ,
    startTime: {
      field:'startTime',
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    } 
  });
```

I try to setup `version:true` to enable [Optimistic Locking](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html#optimistic-locking)
I put it in model

```
  const Vessel = sequelize.define('FDMData', {
    // attributes
    id: {
      field:'vesselId',
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    } ,
    startTime: {
      field:'startTime',
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    } 
  },{
    version:true
   }
);
```

and I get `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name 'version'.`

I also tried to set it as global while init

```
const { DataTypes } = Sequelize;
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: database,
  username: user,
  host: server, 
  password: password,
  dialect: 'mssql',
  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
      useUTC: true,
      dateFirst: 1,
    }
  },
  define:{
      timestamps:false,
      paranoid:false,
      freezeTableName: true,
      version: true
  }
});
```

and again, I get `Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name 'version'.`

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Which OS and DB server are you using?

Comment: What is your sequelize version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set `version: true` and you are creating your database structure manually, sequelize expect to find a column
named `version` on the table : so add a column `version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0` to your tables. 
You can also name the versioning column what ever you want, just passe a string `version: "myVersionColumn"`

If you let sequelize handle the creation of the DB structure, it generate a DDL for the `FDMData` table that look like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FDMData (
    vesselId INTEGER NOT NULL , 
    startTime DATETIME, 
    version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    PRIMARY KEY (vesselId)
)
```

and your code work juste fine. For example

```
Vessel.sync().then(model=> {
// or sequelize.sync()
    console.log(model)
}).catch(error=> {
    console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I created a version-column and set version equal to the respective column in the database. The DDL is generated the way your table is, but inserting values into the the table does not modify the version-column

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there, based on the [docs](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-definition.html#configuration), setting version to true or set it to whatever name you want do the trick

> Enable optimistic locking.  When enabled, sequelize will add a version count attribute
>     to the model and throw an OptimisticLockingError error when stale instances are saved.
>     Set to true or a string with the attribute name you want to use to enable.

however, just in the next section to optimistic locking -Database synchronization- it says

> When starting a new project you won't have a database structure and using Sequelize you won't need to

meaning, sequelize doesn't depend on a sql structure already set in your database for this purpose if you sync your models after you define them except for the database definition, it will automatically create it for you including the version field, here is an example

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = {
  username: "root",
  password: "123",
  tableName: "test",
  options: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      dialect: 'mysql',
      pool: {
        max: 3,
        min: 1,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
      },
      define: {
        timestamps:false,
        paranoid:false,
        freezeTableName: true,
        version: true
      }
    }
};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.tableName, config.username, config.password, config.options);

//and my Model 
  const User= sequelize.define('User', {
    // attributes
    id: {
      field:'Id',
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    } ,
    startTime: {
      field:'startTime',
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    } 
  });

User.sync();
```

if you run this script you will see the following sql statements executed

> Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `User` (`Id` INTEGER
>   NOT NULL , `startTime` DATETIME, `version` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB; 
>   Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `User`

however, if you don't want sequelize to sync your models, you have to explicitly have that field in your already established tables, but not explicitly defined in sequelize model as it will automatically know its there.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an example, a User model (using sequelize v6):

```
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes, Deferrable, DatabaseError } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../lib/db.sequelize').db;

class User extends Model {

}

User.init({
    // The following specification of the 'id' attribute could be omitted
    // since it is the default.
    id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    version: { // Optimistic Locking
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0
    },
    name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: true
        }
    }
}, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'user',
    version: true, // Optimistic Locking
    indexes: [
        {
            name: 'user_id_index',
            method: 'BTREE',
            fields: ['id'],
        },
        {
            name: 'user_email_index',
            method: 'BTREE',
            fields: ['email'],
        }
    ],
    freezeTableName: true
});

module.exports = User;
```

Note that a version **attribute** was added to the model as well as passing the "version: true" to the **options**.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting this error: `column "version" does not exist` while running your migrations, then it means that you have set the `version: true` in your global config after the `SequelizeMeta` table was created.

To fix this:

1. You can delete the `SequelizeMeta` table from your database and run your migrations again
2. You should manually add the `version` column to your `SequelizeMeta`
3. Remove the `version: true` from you global config and add it each of the model separately.